# vb.net 2010 read json url and populate datagridview

Tags: json, vb.net, datagridview

I am a complete newbie to .net scene. I have some experience in php but absolutely none in vb.net 2010.

Below is my code that I am trying to read and populate a datagridview.

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json
    Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim url As String
        url = base_url & "get_report"
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim s As String
        s = reader.ReadToEnd
        MessageBox.Show(s)
        Dim res As results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of results)(s)


        DataGridView1.DataSource = res
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class results
    Public tracker As Integer
    Public dinaya As Date
    Public total As Double
    Public cardname As String
    Public sourcenum As Integer
End Class
```

My issue is that I get this build error which I have no idea on debugging.

Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'WindowsApplication1.results' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

I just don't know what to do.
The message box shows the json result.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

NET EDIT

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
        Dim reader As StreamReader
        Dim url As String
        url = base_url & "get_report"
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)

        response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        reader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())

        Dim s As String
        s = reader.ReadToEnd
        MessageBox.Show(s) 'valid json output here
        Dim res As transactions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of transactions)(s)
        MessageBox.Show(res.cardname) 'pops up the proper field

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class transactions
    Public tracker As Integer
    Public dinaya As Date
    Public total As Double
    Public cardname As String
    Public sourcenum As Integer
End Class
```

My question is to how to read the below json data.

```
[{"tracker":"1","dinaya":"2015-01-01","total":"123","cardname":"Dileep","sourcenum":"1234444"},{"tracker":"12","dinaya":"2015-01-22","total":"1244443","cardname":"Diafasdfleep","sourcenum":"123342344444"}]
```

The moment the json contains more than one array element my code doesn't work. Any method to loop around atleast?

Comment: @Ela Buwa does `s` end up containing valid json? You can test your deserialization independent of the web request by hard-coding a json string that you know should be correct. If deserialization works you can remove the hard-coded value and move to the next step which is consuming the response.

Comment: Sample JSON would be needed to resolve *that* error, but `DataGridView1.DataSource = res` probably wont work either with just public fields

Comment: (I deleted my previous comment because of realising that you are defining the `results`; honestly I didn't even read all your code because `Dim res As results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of results)(s)` + why doesn't it work? was enough for me). You are assigning a variable with a random format to a `DataGridView`'s `DataSource`. Why do you think that it would work at all? Even in case that `res` would be properly built from the JSON inputs, why would the `DataGridView` take your custom-defined type right away? The `DataSource` of a `DataGridView` is expecting a `DataTable`...

Comment: ... It might also accept other types but with limitations (and potential problems). In any case: your attitude of "it is called DataSource, so let's put some data in" is certainly bad. This is not what the high .NET friendliness is supposed to be there for. Learn the format properly and maximise its flexibility as it is supposed to (i.e., to intuitively interact with all the in-built functionalities without having to waste time memorising them). Also it would be better if you could focus on a problem at a time. Prob. 1: JSON serialisation + prob. 2: DataSource of a DataGridView.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments guys. I should have removed the coding for the datagridview to avoid confusion. My final intention was to populate the datagriedview with the json data. I managed to get my code work to for a json file that contains ONE array element. Any idea on how to work with multiple elements? I have updated my answer to reflect my changes